# Swift - Check two arrays are they have same day without looping in a loop

Tags: swift, date

I have 2 arrays `[Date]`

First is with `myDates:[Date]`

Second is with `coreDataDates:[Date]`

I'm going to for loop the second array with Core Data Dates

How to check in the loop is the **DAY** of `myDates` existing in `coreDataDates` ?

I know that, I can use the function `NSCalendar isDate(_:inSameDayAs:)`, but is there a function that I don't need to loop `myDates:[Date]` in the `coreDataDates:[Date]` for loop?

Newbie example:

```
for date1 in coreDataDates{
   for date2 in myDates{
        if(Calendar.current.isDate(date1, inSameDayAs: date2)==true){
             //have it
        }else{
             //don't have it
        }
   }
}
```

I need code that I don't have to use loop in the loop

Comment: Explain your question clearly.

Comment: You can use collection methods `contains`, `first(where:)` or `index(where:)`/`index(of:)` those would provide an early exit if the element (date) is found.

Comment: @iDev750 What you can't understand ? I'm having an array with dates and I want to check is every day is added in the data base. As I said there are two methods and I want to know which is the best for the performance. Also I don't know how to perform the search.

Comment: This seems to me like premature optimization. Dates are in fact stored as a Double (timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate), It uses only 4 bytes for each date. How many dates are you talking about? I don’t think you will have any performance issue when dealing with dates.

Comment: I count 3 different questions, is the first one about how to do a search in Core Data because then you should look into doing a fetch with a predicate.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the question is one. I'm asking which is the best way to search: one by one in Core Data with the method described above or to get the whole Core Data in array and search in myDates with Core Data results. I'm asking which method is the best and when you told me which is the best you have to tell me how to search for the day.

Comment: No one can tell you which one is best, if you have 10 objects in Core Data then fetch all and search in code but if you have 10 million objects in Core Data then it is probably better to do specific search in Core Data. You know your data so you need to decide which route to take, once you have done that then you can come back with a more specific question if you need help with the how part. Either way, we are not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Question updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about time, Apple recommends that you set the time to noon because every day has a noon but not a midnight due to clock changes for daylight saving time.

Convert all dates in the two arrays to noon and then find the union of the two sets:

```
import Foundation

extension Date {
    var noon: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
}

let myDates = [
    DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2018, month: 12, day: 1, hour: 1).date!,
    DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2018, month: 12, day: 2, hour: 2).date!,
    DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2018, month: 12, day: 4, hour: 3).date!
]
let coreDataDates = [
    DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2018, month: 12, day: 1, hour: 4).date!,
    DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2018, month: 12, day: 3, hour: 5).date!,
    DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2018, month: 12, day: 4, hour: 6).date!
]

let myDateSet = Set(myDates.map { $0.noon })
let coreDataDateSet = Set(coreDataDates.map { $0.noon })
let commonDateSet = myDateSet.intersection(coreDataDateSet)
print(commonDateSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of the Set class

```
let dateSet = Set(myDates)
let common = dateSet.intersection(coreDataDates) 
//If you want it as an array
let commonDatesArray = Array(common)
```

See the documentation for the [Set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set) class for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
let date1 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1544019937)
let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1544019936)
let date3 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1544019935)
let date4 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1544019934)
let date5 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1544019933)
let date6 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1544019932)

let arr1 = [date1, date2, date3]
let arr2 = [date4, date5, date6]
print(arr2.filter { arr1.contains($0) }.count > 0 ) // false

let arr1 = [date1, date2, date3]
let arr2 = [date1, date5, date6]
print(arr2.filter { arr1.contains($0) }.count > 0 ) // true
```